# How to make Posts/Blogs mentioning a user appear in the user's profile?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7 and I created a simple page where users are able to create challenges and tag people in their posts. For tagging I used the [Mentions](https://www.drupal.org/project/mentions) module and it works fine, I'm able to visit tagged person's profile.

Now I'm trying to add all the posts/blog entries that are associated with that user to the user's profile. So that every time the user is mentioned, that post would appear on the user's profile.

Is that possible to do? If yes, what would be a possible approach?

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1

Use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module to create "Messages" each of those mentions, similar to what is detailed in the answer to "[How to get notifications in a new window when using the Mentions module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214527/how-to-get-notifications-in-a-new-window-when-using-the-mentions-module/220174#220174)".

#### Step 2

Perform the steps explained in "[How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82)", which can be summarized like so:

1. Create a flag (using the the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module).
2. Create a view 'Messages by user'.
3. Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to flag/unflag messages.
4. Trigger the Rules Component to mark messages (using the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module).
5. Create notifications about Unread Messages (using the "[Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges)" module).

**Notes**:

- Consider Step 5 as a bonus: whenever a new message gets created, the user gets a shiny notification in the format of an iOS-like (red) badge with the number of unread mesages.
- No custom coding involved, only using some of the commonly used contributed modules (and "Menu Badges", a hidden gem ...).