# How to get notifications in a new window when using the Mentions module?

Tags: 7, rules, notifications

I am using the [Mentions](https://www.drupal.org/project/mentions) module to be able to tag other users in a posts.

I also installed the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and made a new rule which sends email and shows a message on site if the logged in user is mentioned in a blog.

But I need notifications like this to be displayed in a new window.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module for this. So that you expand the rule you already have (or clone it in a variation of it) to have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module create message "entities" (which is what you get if you use the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module). And then just use the power of [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display those messages that got created in the format you need (page, block, etc).

Here is a blueprint of what you'd need:

1. Define an appropriate Message type, using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Think of Message types as similar to "Content types", which will be used to create Messages, similar to Nodes. I'd imagine that the message text you'll  want to use is similar to the eMail or messages your existing rule already produces.
2. Enhance your rule with a Rules Action "Create entity" (of type "Message"). Refer to the answer in [Which user related token(s) can be used to create a Rule for setting up a message type?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219680/) for some examples, which are related to these variations of using [Mentions](https://www.drupal.org/project/mentions):

   - A user gets flagged (using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)).
   - A user is mentioned (using [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses)).
3. Make sure to also add a Rules Action to pass any relevant tokens from [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses), via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), as *Replacement tokens* that you can use in your Message type you created with the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module. Refer to [What's the purpose of "Replacement tokens" of a Message type?](http://drupal.placeto.be/node/109) for more details on this.
4. Use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to display the created messages in the format you prefer.